# parallel.foreach is hanging my application

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have a **List(of MyCustomObject)**. This List is the DataSource for TreeView.
Now, all of collected objects must be updated on periodicaly Rising Timer1_Timer event. To update I'm using **Parallel.ForEach**. This works fine in test app, but final application hangs after adding code for calculations, and random number of relults may absent. Please help to fix it.

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports Telerik.WinControls.UI
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Threading
Imports Accessibility

Public Class Form1
    Dim WithEvents bw As New BackgroundWorker

    Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        Upadte(rt.Nodes.Cast(Of RadTreeNode)())
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub Upadte(Of T)(source As IEnumerable(Of T))
        Parallel.ForEach(source, New ParallelOptions With {.TaskScheduler =    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext, .MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5}, AddressOf    zUpdate)
    End Sub

    ' Following fragment is a simple example. Real code is more difficult. It includes Network requests, WQL queries e.t.c.
    ' -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
    Private Shared Sub zUpdate(Of T)(node As T)
        Dim item = TryCast(node, RadTreeNode)
        If item Is Nothing Then
            Return
        End If
        Dim n_node As New RadTreeNode("_" & item.Name)
        n_node.Nodes.Add("Hardware")
        Dim tf As Form = Control.FromHandle(Form1.Handle)
        tf.BeginInvoke(New Action(Function() InlineAssignHelper(item, n_node)))
    End Sub
    ' -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
    Private Shared Function InlineAssignHelper(ByRef target As RadTreeNode, ByVal value As RadTreeNode) As RadTreeNode
        target.Nodes.Add(value.Clone)
        Return target
    End Function
End Class
```

---

Greate idea! I'll check it. By the way, there's no any secret in full code. It's just much more than 1st example. Here is the copy of complete sub zUpdate without some typical queries, which working fine in STA:

```
Private Shared Sub zUpdate(Of T)(anode As T)
    Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher
    Dim tt_node As RadTreeNode = TryCast(anode, RadTreeNode)
    If tt_node Is Nothing Then
        Return
    End If
    Dim t_node As String = tt_node.Name
    Dim n_node As New RadTreeNode With {.Name = "_" & t_node, .Text = "_" & t_node}
    Dim opt As New ConnectionOptions
    opt.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy
    opt.EnablePrivileges = True
    opt.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate
    opt.Username = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials.UserName
    opt.Password = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials.Password
    opt.Authority = "ntlmdomain:" & CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials.Domain
    Dim scope As New ManagementScope("\\" & t_node & "\ROOT\CIMV2", opt)
    Dim query As New ObjectQuery

    If My.Computer.Network.Ping(t_node, 10) = False Then
        Return
        GoTo 1
    End If

    scope.Connect()
    If Not scope.IsConnected Then
        Return
        GoTo 1
    End If

    'Summary
    query.QueryString = "SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem"
    searcher.Scope = scope
    searcher.Query = query

    n_node.Nodes.Add("Summary")
    For Each queryobj As ManagementObject In searcher.Get
        With n_node.Nodes("Summary")
            .Nodes.Add("Name", "Name:" & queryobj("Name"), 6)
            .Nodes.Add("Domain", "Domain:" & queryobj("Domain"), 6)
            .Nodes.Add("Manufacturer", "Manufacturer:" & queryobj("Manufacturer"), 6)
            .Nodes.Add("Model", "Model:" & queryobj("Model"), 6)
            .Nodes.Add("NumberOfLogicalProcessors", "NumberOfLogicalProcessors:" & queryobj("NumberOfLogicalProcessors").ToString, 6)
            .Nodes.Add("NumberOfProcessors", "NumberOfProcessors:" & queryobj("NumberOfProcessors").ToString, 6)
            .Nodes.Add("TotalPhysicalMemory", "TotalPhysicalMemory:" & queryobj("TotalPhysicalMemory").ToString, 6)
            .Nodes.Add("UserName", "UserName:" & queryobj("UserName"), 6)
            .Nodes.Add("Workgroup", "Workgroup:" & queryobj("Workgroup"), 6)
        End With
    Next

    'LogicalDisk
    query.QueryString = "SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk"
    searcher.Query = query
    n_node.Nodes.Add("Hardware")
    With n_node.Nodes("Hardware")
        .Nodes.Add("LogicalDisks")
        With .Nodes("LogicalDisks")
            For Each queryobj As ManagementObject In searcher.Get
                .Nodes.Add("Name", "Name" & ": " & queryobj("Name"), 6)
                With .Nodes("Name")
                    .Nodes.Add("Description", "Description: " & queryobj("Description"), 6)
                    .Nodes.Add("DriveType", "DriveType: " & queryobj("DriveType"), 6)
                    .Nodes.Add("Size", "Size: " & queryobj("Size").ToString, 6)
                    .Nodes.Add("FreeSpace", "FreeSpace: " & queryobj("FreeSpace"), 6)
                    .Nodes.Add("VolumeName", "VolumeName: " & queryobj("VolumeName"), 6)
                    .Nodes.Add("VolumeSerialNumber", "VolumeSerialNumber: " & queryobj("VolumeSerialNumber"), 6)
                End With
            Next
        End With

        'network adapters
        query.QueryString = "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration"
        searcher.Query = query
        .Nodes.Add("NetworkAdapters")
        With .Nodes("NetworkAdapters")
            For Each queryobj As ManagementObject In searcher.Get
                .Nodes.Add(CStr(queryobj("Description")))
                With .Nodes(CStr(queryobj("Description")))
                    .Nodes.Add("DHCPServer", "DHCPServer: " & queryobj("DHCPServer"), 6)
                    .Nodes.Add("DNSDomain", "DNSDomain: " & queryobj("DNSDomain"), 6)
                    .Nodes.Add("DNSHostName", "DNSHostName: " & queryobj("DNSHostName"), 6)
                    .Nodes.Add("MACAddress", "MACAddress: " & queryobj("MACAddress"), 6)
                    .Nodes.Add("SettingID", "SettingID: " & queryobj("SettingID"), 6)
                End With
            Next
        End With
    End With

    'software
    query.QueryString = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Product"
    searcher.Query = query
    n_node.Nodes.Add("Software")
    With n_node.Nodes("Software")
        For Each queryobj As ManagementObject In searcher.Get
            .Nodes.Add(queryobj("Name"))
            With .Nodes(queryobj("Name"))
                .Nodes.Add("InstallDate", "InstallDate: " & queryobj("InstallDate"), 6)
                .Nodes.Add("IdentifyingNumber", "IdentifyingNumber: " & queryobj("IdentifyingNumber"), 6)
            End With
        Next
    End With

    Dim tf As Form = Control.FromHandle(Form2.Handle)
    tf.BeginInvoke(New Action(Function() InlineAssignHelper(tt_node, n_node)))

1:
    If Not searcher Is Nothing Then
        searcher.Dispose()
        scope = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

Private Shared Function InlineAssignHelper(ByRef target As RadTreeNode, ByVal value1 As RadTreeNode) As RadTreeNode
    Dim t_str As String = Now.Date.ToString & Now.TimeOfDay.ToString

    target.Nodes.Add(t_str)
    target.Nodes(t_str).Nodes.Add(value1.Clone)

    Return target
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

> This works fine in test app, but final application hangs after adding
>   code for calculations, and random number of results may absent.

I suspect this means that your problem may lay in the code that you are not showing us.

The most likely candidate is that the code in your *real* `zupdate` method is accessing some sort of shared resource that is deadlocking.

Comment: Greate idea! I'll check it.

Comment: But first I'll try to replace standart collection of nodes by special ConcurrentBag. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah!!.. Just replaced `Upadte(rt.Nodes.Cast(Of RadTreeNode)())` with `Upadte(New ConcurrentBag(Of RadTreeNode)(rt.Nodes))` and collection of Nodes successfuly passed zUpdate!!! _**Nathan, thank you!**_